# How to improve performance of sql query that has UNION and sub-select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a view on mssql 2008. T-SQL Codes is like below,

```
SELECT     *
FROM        View1
WHERE     Category = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         View1 AS Level#1
WHERE    Category = 2 AND NOT EXISTS
                          (SELECT     *
                            FROM          View1
                            WHERE      Level#1.Code = Code AND CategoryCode = 1)
```

**P.S. for codes;**
Code's dataype is nvarchar - View1 is same view

When i perform this code from about 3500 records, results come to screen over than 5 minutes.

How can i modify this code to perform quickly?
Thank you already now for your suggestions.

Comment: Need to add table definition and current indexes to the question. And do you really need `SELECT *`

Comment: And answer the rest: we need to *view* definition too

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (with given information) is a view and `SELECT *`

- A view is simply a macro that expands out to the original tables. So if the view has 4 tables, then your UNION now has the same 4 tables, each used times
- `SELECT *` also means indexes won't be used efficiently, if at all. You'll get scans or key lookups in the execution plan because you can't use covering indexes and the like

If your view is on a single table then it may be salvaged, but otherwise you may as well use a temp table to do it steps.

Comment: view1 is selecting datas from another view and that view is selecting datas many table. so is this code structure right?

Comment: so how can i modify that to perform more faster?

Comment: @TomTom: feel free to post your own answer or demonstrate I'm wrong: SELECT * from a multi table view? Indexes may be used for JOINs and WHEREs if selective enough, but may cause key lookups, otherwise it will just scan the clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what your table / index definition is, so I could be wrong, but this code seems unnecessary at first glance:

```
AND NOT EXISTS
                          (SELECT     *
                            FROM          View1
                            WHERE      Level#1.Code = Code AND CategoryCode = 1)
```

since you already have `WHERE Category = 2` in the second clause of the `UNION ALL`

Comment: (the point being, if I'm right you'll avoid a whole select operation and index scan for the 3500 rows)

Comment: It's not unnecessary, it's a correlated subquery. He wants all rows with Category=1 and all rows with Category=2 but for those codes that do not have any Category=1 row. He could have written it as uncorrelated subquery though.

Comment: this codes is a view's code. when perform this code just select *, datas come to screen quickly. but there are many duplicates records in view1. for example there are 2 records both category = 1 and category = 2. if there is 1 records in category 1 i would'nt like to select in category = 2. i hope this explain is clear. sorry for my pure english.

Comment: I misread Code as the PK, apologies @Kerberos. Also, cool name

Comment: @Alex Norcliffe, not a problem. thank you for your help and interest.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are on SQL Server 2005 or later version, you could try something like this:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Category)
  FROM View1
  WHERE Category IN (1, 2)
)
SELECT
  *  /* this will include the 'rnk' column too;
        in any event, masked output is a very
        discouraged thing to do so you should
        probably specify the columns explicitly */
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
```

If there can never be more than one `Code` per `Category`, replace `RANK()` with `ROW_NUMBER()`, which should be more efficient.

Useful reading:

- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

  - [RANK (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx)
  - [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand your query, but try this and see if you get the same (expected) results:

```
SELECT     *
FROM        View1
WHERE     Category = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM         View1 AS Level#1
LEFT JOIN View1 as XX ON Level#1.code=XX.Code and XX.CategoryCode =1 
WHERE    Level#1.Category = 2 AND xx.code is NULL
```